# Density and Saturated Models.

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider $(\mathbb{Q}; \leq)$ and let $T$ be the theory of dense linear orderings without endpoints.

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be the $\omega_1$ saturated model of $T$. Note that $|\mathfrak{A}|=2^{\aleph_0}$ since $\mathbb{R} \subset A$. However, $\mathbb{R} \neq A$ since $\mathfrak{A}$ has elements of the form "I am smaller than every positive rational, but larger than 0". Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, this element is not in $\mathbb{R}$. However, since $\mathfrak{A}$ is only $\omega_1$ saturated, we don't immediately get elements of the form "I am smaller than every positive real number, but larger than zero". For this to be the case, $\mathfrak{A}$ must be ${2^{\aleph_0}}^{+}$- saturated. Therefore, in some model which is ${2^{\aleph_0}}^+$- saturated, it is clear that $\mathbb{R}$ is not dense in that model.

**Question**: Is $\mathbb{R}$ dense in $\mathfrak{A}$ (the $\omega_1$ saturated model)?

Comment: But if you are smaller than every positive rational you are also smaller that every positive real.

Comment: The question is a bit funny, since there's not a canonical embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathfrak{A}$. But the point is that *no* embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathfrak{A}$ is dense.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Do you have any advice in rephrasing my question?

Comment: Sure: Observe that $\mathbb{R}$ embeds in $\mathfrak{A}$, since certainly $\mathbb{Q}$ embeds in $\mathfrak{A}$, and we can extend the embedding to $\mathbb{R}$ using $\aleph_1$-saturation, since the type of each element of $\mathbb{R}$ is determined by its type over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is any embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathfrak{A}$ dense? The answer is no, as per Rene Schipperus's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbb{R}$ were dense then so to would be $\mathbb{Q}$.